# Using Sherlock ActionBar, Fragment Tab's, ViewPager, PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, preferences

So i have this Preference activty and cant seem to figure out how to make this work or if it can be done. My applications is using Sherlock Actionbar, View-pager and Fragment Tabs. All of my tabs work other than the last one, which is my PreferenceActivity.

```
 public class Prefs extends SherlockPreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("clearcache");
    customPref
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cache Cleared",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Webview.web.clearCache(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });

    Preference customerPref1 = (Preference) findPreference("intent1");
    customerPref1
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Prefs.this, Intent1.class);
                    Prefs.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

This is how i have my Preference Activity setup. Now the main issue is the following when this tab is selected.

LOGCAT

```
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968): java.lang.ClassCastException:      com.application.example.EditPreferences cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at com.application.example.ABSTabsViewPagerActivity$TabsAdapter.getItem(ABSTabsViewPagerActivity.java:106)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:800)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:991)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at      android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:880)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1374)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5204)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
 03-07 10:55:09.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3968):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any Idea's, Examples, Other recommendations, Even other examples of being able to do a Settings page, Most of my settings are just intents to other activities.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to implement a PreferenceActivity into a ViewPager

Comment: Try extending from SherlockFragment, an Activity won't work in the ViewPager

Comment: @Marcin After changing to SherlockFragment, All my 'findPreference' are undefined.

Comment: Turning your class into a Fragment does change a lot of things. There is no `SherlockPreferenceFragment` for you to extend from, but consider extending from `PreferenceFragment`.  You'll still need to modify some code to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load an activity in place of a fragment. That's why it's giving an exception. If your settings are simple intents than there's no need to put them in the preference activity . Simply extend SherlockFragment and place your code there.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yeah im aware of the activity part, just didnt know if there was anyway to make it work. Do you have any good recommendations of making a settings like screen, like a listview fragment that will load in the viewpager

Comment: As Marcin said, you can use `PreferenceFragment` but it will not work for android versions < 3.0 because its not included in the android support library. I suppose you have to use check boxes or radio buttons and handle shared preferences yourself .